# Stacking lidar-derived height raster as ancillary data for segmentation in ENVI?

Tags: dem, lidar, envi, image-segmentation

I get a a black and white image after following these steps.  Does anyone know why I'm not getting a color aerial image beneath the mask?

My setup consists of these steps:

1. I mosaicked several NAIP tiles together (ArcGIS Pro: Mosiac to New Raster), then clipped that raster to a polygon representing my study area.
2. I created a DTM (ground) and DSM (first return) from a LAS dataset (ArcGIS Pro: LAS Dataset to Raster) using the study area polygon as the processing extent, NAD83 UTM 13N as output coord sys. Units are in meters, and I applied a Z factor of 3.2808399 to convert to feet.
3. I used the Minus tool to substract the DTM from the DSM to get a height band.
4. I created an NDVI polygon to use as a mask in ENVI.
5. I used the Segment Only Feature Extraction tool. Input: NAIP raster. Mask: NDVI polygon. Ancillary data: height band. Custom bands: NDVI.

In ENVI, here is the NAIP raster clipped to the study area: [image: naip image in envi]

Here is the height band raster: [image: height band in envi]

Here is the ndvi mask: [image: ndvi mask in envi]

Here is the stacking result from step 5: [image: segmentation result in envi]

There should be an aerial image beneath the mask, not a black and white image. I tried stacking without using the height band as ancillary data, and it worked the way it should. I have used this method successfully to stack bands for segmentation before. It seems obvious there is something wrong with the height band, but I cannot figure out what it is!

Has anyone encountered this before?

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.2, ENVI 5.5 v3.2.